# String that looks like an array to a real array (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, string

I've come up with this monstrosity :

```
echo $value;
And the result is this:

"_aaaaaaa","_bbbbbb","_cccccc","_dddddd"
```

This is i a string....but i want to make it look like this in end.

```
$value= array("_aaaaaaa","_bbbbbb","_cccccc","_dddddd");
```

I've tried everything.How can i make this string into an array like the above ?

Any help here ?
-Thanks

Comment: i messed up my script some way...give me a sec guys to test this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try as following:

```
$value= '"_aaaaaaa","_bbbbbb","_cccccc","_dddddd"';
$array = array_map(function($v) { return trim($v, '"'); }, explode(',', $value));
```

More simply:

```
$array = explode('","', trim($value, '"'));
```

Comment: nope none work... :( The thing is i get my result from another function.
I parse some files and create that value like this:

$value = getHeadersInArray($parentDirectory2);

This echoed...is what i showed you....

Comment: @user1033882 Nope? Working here -> http://3v4l.org/ZN59e If it's not working with  your string then your string isn't formatted as you're telling us it is.

Comment: This is the function that return that value: http://3v4l.org/X23iR

If i echo $value i get what i said at the top...

Edit: sorry...wrong one.

Comment: `var_dump()` the string being returned from that function and paste the value it gives you in your question. The function you're showing says nothing of the return value. In it you're building an array of `$items`, and yet it's returning a variable named `$value` which doesn't appear to have been defined inside the function itself.

Comment: yeah i simplified the 1st post...so i didnt get into deep trying to avoid all this...lol, I thought there was a simple way of just converting a string to an array but like i thought...this is harder than it seems. 
var_dumping the value brings :string(65) ""_aaaaaaa","_bbbbbb","_ccccccc","dddddd""

I have to keep changing the results to _aaaaa _bbbb but you can imagine i just cant post publicly this data...hence these values

Comment: Did you cut some of the string off? There aren't 65 characters in the string being returned from the var_dump you've pasted (edit, ok, I see the reason now). Regardless though, either of the above should work, it's the same string -> http://3v4l.org/J1I9H.

Comment: I just realized something....i was getting this : http://3v4l.org/Mcmcr

but i used a function that i got from a guy to remove the double quotes...and probably thats what messed things up

used this guys function to implode all the arrays i was getting to one. http://3v4l.org/UuUn2

Comment: Both functions I posted remove the double quotes as part of the process, drop whatever function you got from a guy, and try without that.

Comment: I'll give you the point cause its not your fault and i am pretty sure your way would solve the problem and i've taken enough of your time.
Thank you all!

Comment: @Crisp, My only concern is that the two solution of yours do not do the same. First splits the array by commas then removes the quotes from all parts (elegant solution, I must say) but the second removes surrounding commas first and only then splits to parts thus leaving the quotes that was not in the beginning or end of the original string. They are not equivalent. I think for future reference that should be pointed out in your answer

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, `$value = explode(',', $value);` should turn this into an array.

Comment: well yeah thats what i was trying to do...but like this its not working...cause i am using this array like this after:

foreach ($value as $key => $kv) {....}

and its not doing it correctly...but if i write the whole thing as 
$value= array("_aaaaaaa","_bbbbbb","_cccccc","_dddddd");

Then i get the right results.

Comment: @fejese has your answer then :)

Answer (score 0):

Your question would need more specific description I guess what you are trying to achieve but if you have a string that contains values separated by `,` and surrounded with quotes then you want to do something like this:

```
$value = explode(',', $value);
foreach ($value as &$val) {
    $val = trim($val, '"');
}
```

Comment: this results: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Change the first line to: `$values = explode(',', $value);`

Comment: that only brings : _aaaaaaa

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help

```
 $str = '"_aaaaaaa","_bbbbbb","_cccccc","_dddddd"';
$value = explode(',', $str);
foreach ($values as $val) {
    $val = trim($val, '"');
}
```

Comment: To give you the whole background of the function...I am parsing a directory and gather (while i am parsing the files) all the headers the files have into an array...At the end of the function i am returning the array...hence the $value = getHeadersInArray($parentDirectory2);

That $value echoed...is the result i gave you...I need to do this to like this :
print_r($value) to see it...This is how after the conversion to an array it should look like.
Array ([0] =>_aaaaaaa [1] => _bbbbbb [2] => _cccccc [3] => _dddddd )